# Как получить множественное поле из админке вордпресс?

Tags: php, wordpress

вот поле

```
<input type="number" step="any" min="1" name="wwsd_flat_discount_rate[]" value="10">
```

так пробовал с не множественными получилось с этим нет

```
echo get_post_meta($product->get_id() ,'wwsd_flat_discount_rate[0]', true);
```

Comment: $wwsd = get_post_meta($product->get_id() ,'wwsd_flat_discount_rate', true);
echo $wwsd[0];

Comment: выдает ошибку  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in

Comment: сделай var_dump( $wwsd );

Comment: отдало array(0) , хотя заполнены